Error react-native-nested-scroll-view in android emulator
I am trying to compile an application developed in react-native v6.2.2. The problem I have is that I have installed react-native-nested-scroll-view but when I run npm run androd I get the following error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-nested-scroll-view'.


Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':react-native-nested-scroll-view:classpath'.
Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3.
Searched in the following locations:
- https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.3/gradle-2.3.3.pom
If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
Required by:
project :react-native-nested-scroll-view

gradle-wrapper.properties:
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8.1-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists

build.gradle file:
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        playServicesVersion = "17.0.0"
        androidMapsUtilsVersion = "2.2.0"
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        agp_version = '4.2.0'
        kotlin_version = "1.5.31"
        
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {
        
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:$agp_version")
        //classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3")
        classpath('com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5')
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
       
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            // Remove this override in 0.65+, as a proper fix is included in react-native itself.
            force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
        }
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
       
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
        

    }
} 

package.json
"react-native-nested-scroll-view": "^9.0.0",
I have added inside dependencies classpath(‘com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3’)
I have more repositories like google, mavenCentral and maven
I have removed the node-module folder and running npm install

Look at this StackOverflow question, it returns the same error but under a different situation. It could be the same underlying problem.
Me, personally I think you have to change your distributionUrl to the correct version.
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8.1-bin.zip

to
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.3.3-bin.zip

